# Calling FastAPI Post Request from a HTML form action in different folder not working

Tags: python, html, forms, fastapi

I want to execute a fastApi post method from a formular submit, I searched all the web about calling from a different folder but found nothing so far. My projectstructure is as following:

```
├── index.html
├── assets
└── backend
    ├── main.py
    └── ...
```

main.py Post method:

```
@app.post(path="/uploadImages")
async def extract_data_from_images(images: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    return images[0].filename + " Hello World"
```

Inside index.html, the form should trigger the post method defined in main.py. But it does nothing.

```
<form id="uploadform" action="/uploadImages" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="images" name="images" multiple data-max="2" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" >
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<textarea>Here should be data returned from FastAPI response</textarea>
```

I also tried setting action path to  "./backend/main/uploadImages",  "./backend/uploadImages" "./backend/main.py/uploadImages", neither of them worked.

Normally with the example code given in the post method, the browser must open a new site with a json raw string displaying filename + "Hello World", or not? If not, how can I make it that return in the textarea of the given index.html?

Testing from Fastapi docs is displaying the string so it is no serverside fault.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll have to use Javascript to retrieve the content from the API request (using `fetch` or an `XMLHttpRequest` and then insert the returned content into the `textarea`. Your endpoint (`action`) is correct according to your `@app.post` decorator.

Comment: I only got the post working by hardcoding the absolute path of the webserver, however it is obvious that this is not efficient. As for the javascript fetch: So submit should be done there and not with the form?

Comment: Ah, if you're just opening the HTML page, that won't work properly. Instead, you should use a `TemplateResponse` in FastAPI to deliver the HTML content - that way it will be delivered from the same host as the one that will accept the request from the client. If you want to host these on different servers - yes, in that case you'll have to provide the whole URL to where the post should happen (or give it to fetch - but in that case you'll also need CORS support to let Javascript make cross domain requests).

Comment: The Javascript part is necessary if you just want the output to appear there - but if you use a template, you can insert the data into the template and return it directly instead (usually with `{{ varname }}` in Jinja2).

Answer (score 0):

You can add another endpoint to serve your HTML pages, for instance:

**main.py:**

```
import uvicorn

from datetime import datetime
from typing import List

from fastapi import FastAPI, File, Request, UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory=".") # Change this path accordingly


@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})


@app.post(path="/uploadImages")
async def extract_data_from_images(images: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    return f"Name: {images[0].filename}, now: {datetime.now()}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="localhost", port=8000, reload=True)
```

You can then make the request from JavaScript:

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="uploadform" action="/uploadImages" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="images" name="images" multiple data-max="2" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" >
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
  </form>

  <textarea id="box">Here should be data returned from FastAPI response</textarea>

  <script>
    const box = document.getElementById("box");

    uploadform.onsubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      let res = await fetch("/uploadImages", {
        method: "POST",
        body: new FormData(uploadform),
      });

      if (res.ok) {
        let result = await res.text();
        box.innerHTML = result;
      } else {
        box.innerHTML = `Response error: ${res.status}`;
      };
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes thank you, it should work but the anonymous onsubmit function wont fire due to Cross-Origin Resource Sharing along "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource", and allowing Firefox permissions does not help either

Comment: Both endpoints are served from the same domain in my example so that shouldn’t be the case. What URL did you use to test this?

Comment: Yes, like I said my local ip http:// http://192.168.178.99:8000/uploadImages for both form and fetch

Comment: When using my example, just go to `http://localhost:8000/`, this will show the HTML form that will use the relative path to the backend API otherwise check FastAPI [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/) for CORS.